# Jenkins - Create Git branch on build

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build and on completion I wish to create a branch in the remote repository for the release.

I have the git publish setup like this:
[image]

But when I run it tagging seems to go OK but the branching gives:

```
ERROR: Failed to push branch RELEASE-5 to jsched
 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe push 
 https://myid@git.server:9443/scm/win/jsched.git HEAD:RELEASE-5" returned status code 1:

 stderr: error: unable to push to unqualified destination: RELEASE-5
  The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
  begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://myid@git.server:9443/scm/win/jsched.gitt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing your local RELEASE-ID branch to the remote, but the problem is that since it's a newly created branch it has no upstream defined, thus git does not know where to push the commits.

If you where doing this "by hand" you would have told git to use remote/RELEASE-ID as upstream. Jenkins interface does not allow you to define such behavior. Maybe you can achieve something similar with a script.

Comment: In my case, I am trying to go with the following steps: 1. Build master branch, 2. Create a development branch from master (should provide the name dynamically), 3. Edit a file in development branch, 4. Push this branch to repo 5. Build it

I think I should start writing a script rather than configuring multiple JOBS in jenkins and trying to execute them via command line because, how would I know when has each step completed? Unless you can suggest that this process can be done in a single jenkins JOB?